# Appcelerator Studio and Modules

Tags: appcelerator

What is the recommended way to install 3rd party modules in Appcelerator project so that once checked into SVN/Git the module is available to everyone who checks out the project?

Comment: check if the module exists in http://gitt.io/ and use the gitTio CLI - it's like npm for Titanium

Answer (score 0):

Just put them into ROOT/modules and then for iOS /iphone and /android

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded zip can be added to the root of your project. It will then automatically extract the zip, and remove the zip when building.

Or, as Sebastian says, you can extract the ZIP yourself, and put them in the modules folder. Every module should already have the `modules` folder as a root, in that case copy the correct folders into your modules directory, or copy/paste the extracted modules folder into your project and merge folders.

Easiest is still just adding the zip